# CSS styles not being applied to HTML within a Vue Component

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, css-selectors, vuejs2

I am trying to create a rotating text animation using `Vue.js` and I used this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rpQGPR) as inspiration.

- I got all the `HMTL` elements properly in place (i.e., as in the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rpQGPR) mentioned). In short:

  - each word is formed of several `<span>` elements, each containing one letter.
  - following a specific time interval, each `<span>` that holds a letter gets applied an `.in` and `.out` `CSS` class. This goes on indefinitely.
  - here is what it looks like in the `DOM`:

    [image]
- the problem is that no matter what `CSS` selectors I use, I can't target the `.in` and `.out` classes, unless I do it via `Developer Tools` in `Chrome`:

  - original output:

    [image]
  - output after I added the classes in `Developer Tools`:

    [image]

Here is the bare minimum code of my `Vue Component`:

```
<template>
    <div id="app-loading">  
        <div class="words">
            <span v-for="setting in settings" v-html="setting.lettersHTML" :id="setting.id" class="word"></span>    
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                settings: [
                    { word: 'WordOne', id: 1, lettersArray: null, lettersHTML: null },
                    { word: 'WordTwo', id: 2, lettersArray: null, lettersHTML: null }
                ],
                currentWord: 1
            }
        },

        created() {
            this.splitLetters();
        },

        mounted() {
            setInterval(this.changeWord, 1500);
        },

        methods: {
            splitLetters() {
                this.settings.forEach((setting) => {
                    let letters = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < setting.word.length; i++) {
                        let letter = `<span class="letter">${ setting.word.charAt(i) }</span>`;
                        letters.push(letter);
                    }
                    setting.lettersArray = letters;
                    setting.lettersHTML = letters.join('');
                });
            },

            changeWord() {
                let current = document.getElementById(this.currentWord).getElementsByTagName('span');
                let next = (this.currentWord == this.settings.length) ? document.getElementById(1).getElementsByTagName('span') : document.getElementById(this.currentWord + 1).getElementsByTagName('span');
                // Animate the letters in the current word.
                for (let i = 0; i < current.length; i++) {
                    this.animateLetterOut(current, i);
                }
                // Animate the letters in the next word.
                for (let i = 0; i < next.length; i++) {
                    this.animateLetterIn(next, i);
                }
                this.currentWord = (this.currentWord == this.settings.length) ? 1 : this.currentWord + 1;
            },

            animateLetterOut(current, index) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    current[index].className = 'letter out';
                }, index * 300);
            },

            animateLetterIn(next, index) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    next[index].className = 'letter in';
                }, 340 + (index * 300));
            }
        }
    }
</script>


<style lang="scss" scoped>
    #app-loading {
        font-size: 4rem;
    }

    .words, .word {
        border: 1px solid rosybrown;
    }

    .letter {
        text-decoration: underline; // Not working.
    }

    .letter.in {
        color: red; // Not working.
    }

    .letter.out {
        color: blue; // Not working.
    }
</style>
```

What goes wrong that prevents these classes from being applied?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're using `v-html`, but that [doesn't work with scoped styles](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html).

> DOM content created with `v-html` are not affected by scoped styles, but you can still style them using deep selectors.

Comment: You made my day! Thanks for the link.

Comment: The `&::v-deep` selector saved me :) Thanks!

Comment: As @mitchell-seedorf and @q10viking describe below: `::v-deep` is deprecated. Use `:deep(...)` instead. See https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#deep-selectors

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me:

```
<template>   
    <div class="a" v-html="content"></div> 
</template>

<script>   
    export default { 
        data() {
           return {
              content: 'this is a <a class="b">Test</a>',
           }
        },
    } 
</script>

<style scoped>   
.a ::v-deep .b { 
     color: red;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: As @mitchell-seedorf and @q10viking describe below: `::v-deep` is deprecated. Use `:deep(...)` instead. See https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#deep-selectors

Answer (score 5):

Yes,

> v-html

doesn't work with scoped styles.

As Brock Reece explained in his article [Scoped Styles with v-html](https://medium.com/@brockreece/scoped-styles-with-v-html-c0f6d2dc5d8e), it should be solved like this:

```
<template>   
    <div class="a" v-html="content"></div> 
</template>

<script>   
    export default { 
        data() {
           return {
              content: 'this is a <a class="b">Test</a>',
           }
        },
    } 
</script>

<style scoped>   
.a >>> .b {
color: red;   
}
</style>
```

Comment: Strange enough, to me `.a >>> .b` does not work. Instead, `.a ::v-deep .b` works every time.

Comment: As @mitchell-seedorf and @q10viking describe below: `::v-deep` is deprecated. Use `:deep(...)` instead. See https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#deep-selectors

Answer (score 2):

Vue3: In Single-File Components, scoped styles will not apply to content inside v-html, because that HTML is not processed by Vue's template compiler.

You can use :deep() inner-selector in Vue3 project.

Here is a example：

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import {onMounted,ref } from 'vue'
const content = ref("")

onMounted(()=>{
    window.addEventListener('keydown',event =>{
        content.value = `
            <div class="key">
                <span class="content">${event.keyCode}</span>
                <small>event.keyCode</small>
            </div>
        `
    })
})

</script>

<template>
    <div class="container" v-html="content">
    </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>  

.container{
    display: flex;
    
    :deep(.key){
        font-weight: bold;
        
        .content{
            font-size: 1.5rem;
        }
        
        small{
            font-size: 14px;
        }
    }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most answers are deprecated now that Vue3 is out.
Up-to-date usage of **deep** selector:

```
.letter{
  &:deep(.in) {
    color:blue;
  }
  &:deep(.out) {
    color:red;
  }
}
```